# Send variable data to another function on the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables, export

I'm trying to send data from a variable named "api" to another function inside the same file, but I get undefined on the terminal:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const soap = require('soap');


const url = 'myurl'

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer().array());


app.post("/orders", async (req, res, next) =>{
  //const token = req.body.token;
  const cnpj   = req.body.cnpj;
  const pedido = req.body.nrPedido;
  var resultapi;

  soap.createClient(url, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      //client
      console.log('ok')
      client.consultaNFSe({
        token: 'mytoken',
        cnpj: cnpj,
        nrNota: '',
        nrPedido: pedido
      }, (err, res) => {
        resultapi = res; // this is the value that I want, comes from the response above
        exports.resultapi
        console.log(res);
      })
    }
  })
  
  var api = this.resultapi;
  console.log(resultapi);
  
  res.json(["Test"]);
 
  });
  
  //export app
  
  module.exports = app;
```

I'm trying with "exports", but the result is always undefined. The "console.log(res)" returns the response from soap client function, but what I want is this value outside the function, I want to send it to the response on the "res.json" part.

Comment: Looks like an async issue. The console log is run before the assignment resolves, so it's undefined. Also, do you need the "this"?

Comment: I think I didn't get the point